# sqlalchemy: join для таблиц с разных серверов

Tags: sql, python-3.x, join, sqlalchemy

Ситуация следующая: допустим есть два сервера **s_1** и **s_2**. Используюя sqlalchemy я извлекаю итоговую таблицу с первого (таблица **t_1**) и второго серверов (таблица **t_2**). 
Необходимая мне таблица - это таблица получаемя черех **join()** по id_1 для **t_1** и id_2 для **t_2**.

**Вопрос**: возможно ли как-то провести этот **join** для таблиц **t_1** и **t_2**, хранящихся на разных серверах? (Если это возможно сделать в виде похожем на код ниже, это было бы лучшее решение)

```
...

result_table = select([
    t_1.c.field_1,
    t_2.c.field_2
]).select_from(
      t_1.join(
           t_2,
           t_1.c.id_1 == t_2.c.id_2
      )
)

?? how to execute this query ??
```

Answer (score 0):

Join же производится не алхимией, а средствами базы данных..

Вероятно нужно настроить это все в самой базе (если база это позволяет) так что вторая таблица будет или "реплицироваться" из другого сервера - или быть "соединением" (cross-database-querying)

Могу ошибаться но про стратегию "внешнего соединения" нагуглил https://www.compose.com/articles/cross-database-querying-in-compose-postgresql/